# Замена вхождений плюса регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения и функции `replace` с помощью javascript заменить все плюсы `+` на какую-либо нужную мне строку. Я как ни пытался, он или заменяет один плюс, или вообще не заменяет, т.е. интерпретирует его как специальный символ.

Comment: Можно его экранировать, вот так : \+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Андрей Аршинов](/users/2186/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) прав: символы имеющие специальное значение в регулярных выражениях экранируются. Чтобы заменялись все вхождения нужно указать флаг `g`. В результате

```
alert("1 + 2 + 3 = ?".replace(/\+/g, "plus"));
```

выведет строку

> 1 plus 2 plus 3 = ?