# Символы в javascript

Tags: javascript

как сделать во всем тексте замену `.[` на `. [`. То есть, поставить пробел между спецсимволами. Например, в тексте: `Он вышел.[Алексей]. И ту же вернулся его брат.[Игорь]`

Делал через `str.replase('.[', '. [')`, но оно заменяет лишь первую пару символов.

Comment: А сама как пыталась реализовать, что именно не получается?

Comment: `str.replace(/\.\[/g, ". [")`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена всех вхождений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467106/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Comment: Еще похожие вопросы: [Заменить все символы в JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97849/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-javascript), [Замена вхождений плюса регулярным выражением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/75099/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Answer (score 1):

используйте регулярное выражение с флагом g

```
'Он вышел.[Алексей]. И ту же вернулся его брат.[Игор]'.replace(/\.\[/g, '. [')
```

Comment: точку  не хотите экранировать?

Comment: да, вы правы. поправил